# Data Factory - unzip a password protected zip

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am successfully downloading a ZIP from a secure FTP site into my Blob. However, this is a special case and the ZIP is password protected. It seems my only option is special code, but I am unsure what that exactly means. I have never coded data factories, only used the UI with advanced expressions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

Per my observation and test,it seems ADF only supports decompression of zip file though,it is not allowed for password protected zip file.

[image]

As workaround,i suggest you following the solutions mentioned in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs-legacy#unsupported-file-types-and-compression-formats):

1.Use Azure Function Activity to decompress protected file with function code.You could choose your desired development language.

2.Use Custom Activity to decompress the file with task which is executed on the Azure Batch node actually.

Comment: I've used Custom Activity and Azure Batch in ADF to unzip blobs using the ZipArchive class, but last I checked .NET does not natively support password protected Zip files (but I'm sure there are 3rd party libraries you could incorporate). If the files are large, be aware of the time limits in Azure Functions: https://build5nines.com/azure-functions-extend-execution-timeout-past-5-minutes/